# XSLT or XPATH: Test for <body>/<div>

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to test for a condition of an html `<body>` immediately followed by a `<div>`, as in, there is nothing between them.

This is an example that didn't work `<xsl:if test="//div[preceding::*[1][self::body]][1]">`. Other path statements falsely hit on `<divs>` deeper in the document.

I'm working in XSLT 2.0 and Xpath 2 or 3.

Comment: The reason your attempt doesn't work is that the preceding axis does not include any ancestor nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `body/node()[1][self::div]` you check that the first child node of the `body` element is a `div` element.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find any `div` element that is the first child element of a `body`?

```
//div[parent::body][not(preceding-sibling::*)]
```

If you require the div element to be the first child *node* of the `body` (not just the first child *element*, so no text nodes or comments in between the opening `<body>` and `<div>` either) then you could use

```
//div[parent::body][not(preceding-sibling::node())]
```

A refinement would be to allow for whitespace between the two opening tags but not non-whitespace text nodes:

```
//div[parent::body][not(preceding-sibling::*)]
                   [not(preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()])]
```

(this is not necessary if your stylesheet does `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` as that would ignore whitespace-only text nodes entirely).